# Groovy end exception different from exception thrown

Tags: exception, groovy

I am running into an extremely strange behavior in Groovy. When I throw an exception from a closure in a Script, the end exception that was thrown was different.

Here are the code and the details:

```
public class TestDelegate {

    def method(Closure closure) {
        closure.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST);
        closure.delegate = this;
        closure.call();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make Script from File
        File dslFile = new File("src/Script.dsl");
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
        Script dslScript = shell.parse(dslFile);

        TestDelegate myDelegate = new TestDelegate();

        dslScript.metaClass.methodMissing = {
            // will run method(closure)
            String name, arguments ->
            myDelegate.invokeMethod(name, arguments);
        }

        dslScript.metaClass.propertyMissing = {
            String name ->

            println "Will throw error now!"
            throw new MyOwnException("errrrror");
        }

        dslScript.run();
    }
}

class MyOwnException extends Exception {
    public MyOwnException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Script.dsl:

```
method {
    println a;
}
```

So the plan is that when I run the `main()` method in `TestDelegate`, it will run the DSL script, which calls for the method `method()`. Not finding it in the script, it will invoke `methodMissing`, which then invokes `method()` from `myDelegate`, which in turns invoke the closure, setting the delegate to the `testDelegate`. So far, so good. Then the closure is supposed to try printing out "a", which is not defined and will thus set off `propertyMissing`, which will will throw `MyOwnException`.

When I run the code, however, I get the following output:

```
Will throw error now!
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: TestDelegate
```

Now, it must have reached that catch block, since it printed "Will throw error now!" It must have thrown `MyOwnException` too! But somewhere along the lines, `MyOwnException` was converted to `MissingPropertyException`, and I have no idea why. Does anyone have any idea?

P.S. if I remove `closure.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST)` from `TestDelegate#method()`, the code acts as expected and throws `MyOwnException`. But I really need the `setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST)` for my DSL project. And I would prefer to know the root cause of this rather than just removing a line or two and see that it works without understanding why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what essentially happens: With a delegate-first resolve strategy, the Groovy runtime first tries to access property `a` on `myDelegate`, which results in a `MissingPropertyException` because no such property exists. Then it tries `propertyMissing`, which causes a `MyOwnException` to be thrown. Eventually the runtime gives up and rethrows the first exception encountered (a design decision), which happens to be the `MissingPropertyException`.

With an owner-first resolve strategy, `propertyMissing` is consulted first, and hence `MyOwnException` is eventually rethrown.

Looking at the stack trace and source code underneath should provide more evidence.

Comment: Hence there is no other way around this except for setting the resolve strategy to owner first then?

Comment: There are different ways out depending on what you are trying to achieve. For example, you could move the propertyMissing into the delegate. By the way, a good way to implement script-based DSLs is with a custom script base class.